# Al intentar volver de una ventana a otra, no pasa nada

Tags: java, mvc

Estoy intentando conectar dos ventanas, una de menú y otra de alumnos.

La idea es una vez estando en la ventana menu al dar click en: "ALUMNOS" me lleve a la ventana alumnos, y en la ventana alumnos al dar click en "Volver" me regrese a la ventana menú.

El código que utilizo para ir desde menú hacia alumnos es el siguiente:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent listen) {

       if (listen.getSource() == jmen.btnAlumnos) {

           JAlumnos ja = new JAlumnos();
           ja.setVisible(true);
           ja.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
           jmen.dispose();
           
           
       }
```

y el que utilizo para volver de alumnos a menú es este:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent listen) {

                if (e.getSource() == jalum.btnVolver) {
            
            JMenu jmen = new JMenu();
            jmen.setVisible(true);
            jalum.dispose();          
        }
```

El problema está en que al querer volver de alumnos a menú, cuando doy click en el botón *volver*, no pasa nada, no salta error, incluso intenté con un `try` pero no salta ningún error. No sé que pueda estar pasando.

Comment: Quizás quieras dejar 2 instancias únicas de las ventanas, ya que estas creando una y otra vez la ventana al presionar alguno de esos botones, también en el segundo extracto de código estas creando un JMenu vació, este es un componente para las barras de menú JMenuBar no una ventana, por lo tanto no se "abre". una ventana como tal. Intenta revisar eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer el error se trataba de que yo utilicé clases de control para dar visibilidad a las ventanas algo parecido a lo que dijo @JFrame, debia llamar al control de la ventana y no a la ventana como tal, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hace algún tiempo tuve un problema parecido al tuyo, la solución es que debes agregar los componentes incluyendo los botones a un `JPanel` para luego usar los métodos que esta clase posee. Estos son `removeAll()` y `updateUI()`.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if (e.getSource() == boton) {//cuando presionamos boton alumnos
        panel.removeAll();//quitamos todos los componentes del menu profesores
        panel.add(boton2);//agregamos todos los componentes, que deben haber sido creados en el constructor
        panel.updateUI();//actualizamos la ventana

    }
    if (e.getSource() == boton2) {//presionamos el boton profesores
        panel.removeAll();//quitamos todo del menu alumnos
        panel.add(boton);//agregamos componentes
        panel.updateUI();//actualizamos

    }

}
```